# PHP Framework / Library Suggestions for a Backend

Tags: php, frameworks, admin, backend

I am about to start to developing backend site of a php project. Companies and site admins will login to this site and manage their data on the project.

My previous admin panel experiences were full of agony and pain. So I want to make sure that I choose correct tools for my purpose.

By the way, please note, I'm not looking for scaffolding. There won't be much tables in my database. Instead, there will be complex logic between entities.

I want clear seperation of markup and logic code and easy-to-use and standardized user-interface.

Thank you.

### Edit:

I understand this is very subjective. This is why I call it suggestion. I want to try a few of chunks of code before going along with one of them.

Comment: this is very subjective as much of this is down to personal preference. its also worth noting that no framework is a silver bullet to your issues if you have struggled in the past. At the very least you need to clearly define your objectives and go from there

Answer (score 2):

There is no perfect answer for this, it depends a lot of your (and your team) programming experience and your project's requirements.

As it talks about PHP and backoffice, I suggest you look at [symfony framework](http://www.symfony-project.org/). It's a RAD framework with great admin features and tons of plugins easing backpanel developement.

I understand you don't want scaffolding, in symfony you can choose to use a very customizable admin generator or build your own forms/listings (or mix between both, using generated as a good code base and extending it).

It comes with a great separation of concerns as it uses MVC paradigm, but aside from MVC it has form management sub-framework which can help a lot developing backoffice.

Be careful if you're not familiar with PHP5 OOP and MVC it could be little complex to learn and understand, but if your planning could allow you to have time to learn symfony programming, it's an experience I would recommand to every PHP developer.

This framework is very well documented, and as an introduction tutorial they offer a class around a website example with its backend application.

Of course, this is subjective and others would perhaps recommend you other choices.

Comment: I'm familiar with OOP and MVC. Actually I was using Codeigniter before (I wasn't unhappy with it, just for the record). But I'm looking for alternatives. I find Symfony quite powerful yet I think it has relatively longer learning curve. I'm more eager to start with easier frameworks.

Comment: I've got the same MVC framework usage history, starting with codeigniter then moving to symfony, going through few project with an homebrew MVC stack but doing application developement and framework maintenance on the same time was way too complicated and do not take advantage of reusing very good open source code. Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

Only recently went through a couple of frameworks about a month ago for a site I was working on and found CodeIgniter was easiest to get up and running and had the best documentation and tutorials.

http://codeigniter.com/

Alternatives are symphony, cakePHP and Kohona